# Boot a debian linux installed on SD card from USB ram reader into VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

The title says it all! I need to boot a debian linux installed on SD card. I have a USB ram reader. I want to boot system in virtalbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line tool:

```
vboxmanage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename out.vmdk -rawdisk (path to drive)
```

If youre on linux/unix the path to drive will be something like /dev/sdb1, on windows its probably c:\

Comment: Thought this command creates the `out.vmdk`, but VB can't boot it.

Comment: try running the command with sudo :) 

Edit: And don't forget to A) delete the first out.vmdk before you start and B) chmod it to 777 so you can access it from your own account

Comment: I already tried ... VB can't boot them :-(